# How do I make sparse solvers to accept custom matvec function insted of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, matrix, libraries, mpi

I have tried it with `Lis`, `Intel mkl` and `PETSc`. Everywhere you need to pass an  actual matrix to `GMRES` or other similar iterative solver, while I want  to pass just function which multiplies my matrix on vector (my matrix is  having special structure and forming it completely is inefficient).

There is no problem for me writing simple solver which would accept my custom matrix-vector product myself, but I think this kind of problem  should be probably already figured out and implemented in many  libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PETSc does this. See [the documentation for `MatShell`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MATSHELL.html) and Section 3.3 in [the manual](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manual.pdf).